# String not checked correctly for stop words

Tags: java, stop-words

I am reading stop words from a file, which I am saving in a `HashSet`. I compare said `HashSet` with a `String` to check for stop words.

If I put a single stop word, such as "the", in the `String`-variable, my output is "Yes". However, if I put something like "Apple is it" or "it is an apple", the output is "No", despite the fact that both `String`-variables contain stop words.

Here's the whole program, containing two methods, one for reading the file and one for removing the stop words:

```
private static HashSet<String> readFile(){
    Scanner x = null;
    HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();

    try {
        x = new Scanner(new File("StopWordsEnglish"));
        while(x.hasNext()){
            hset.add(x.next());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        x.close();
    }
    return hset;
}

public static void removeStopWords(){
    HashSet<String> hset = readFile();
    System.out.println(hset.size());
    System.out.println("Enter a word to search for: ");
    String search = "is";
    String s = search.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(s);

    if (hset.contains(s)) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Debugger and find it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling I'm not reading your question correctly.  But here goes.

Assuming:

```
String search = "it is an apple";
```

Then you should probably split the string and check each word individually.

```
String[] split = search.split(" ");
for (String s : split) {
if (hset.contains(s.toLowerCase()) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
    break; //no need to continue if a stop word is found
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Splitting on spaces sounds like a good and appropriate thing to do in this case, but I wanted to add that tokenizing can be a difficult and subtle problem, for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/opennlp_tokenization.htm